# Google Script parsing text

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, google-apps-script

I have a Google Script program that is working all but parsing text. I'm having trouble finding the right functions or regular expressions to get the job done. It should pull a name out of an email (which should be the first thing in the email).

Here's what I'm trying to parse out so far:

```
Derek antrican<br />
<br />
==================================================================<br />
This mobile text message is brought to you by AT&amp;T<br />
```

Basically I want the code to take the current string above, sort out the first one or two full words (anything before the html line break tag) and assign the resulting string to the variable "parse".

Here's what I have so far for the code:

```
//var loc = body.findText("\A\w*\s\w*");
//var ele = loc.getElement();
//var parse = ele.getText();
```

I'm new to both regular expressions and javaScript, so I could just be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method that doesn't require regular expressions is to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on " <br "  and take the first element:

var parsed_text = body.split('<br')[0];